# ApostropheCMS - why I'm getting error message while commiting changes in admin bar?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm getting this error every time I commit things in admin bar (pieces, pages). I have no idea why. I use apostrophe version: "^2.220.7". Anyone had a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "commit things in admin bar"? Can you share related code?

Answer (score 2):

Apostrophe 3.x does not have this issue because it is completely namespaced, but in Apostrophe 2.x you do have to take care not to replace the version of jQuery that Apostrophe is using so that it does not lose its plugins, like the `jsonCall` plugin.

Your own custom frontend code, or something being imported by it (for instance via a raw HTML widget), is inserting a different version of jQuery, overwriting the version of jQuery that Apostrophe 2.x needs in order to function.

If you imported that different version of jQuery yourself, we recommend that you stop doing that and set the `jQuery: 3` option to the `apostrophe-assets` module instead, so that a modern version of jQuery is provided by Apostrophe.

If it is happening because of a raw HTML widget that brings in third-party code that replaces jQuery, you can temporarily disable it by adding `?safe_mode=1` to your URL and then edit the page and remove the offending widget.